# Luxon/JavaScript get round days difference compare with day strings and today's Date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, date-comparison, luxon

I'm just getting started with [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) and JavaScript's 'Date'. I use the following date format: `Sat Feb 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`. I want to compare the dates with today's date and get the days difference from this format `Sat Feb 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`. However, I am receiving decimal days '2.5154091898148145' when my expected output is two days. I don't how to fix it.

Also I want to get next dates and previous dates.

Thank you in advanced.

```js
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");

const today = new Date();
const day =
  "Sat Feb 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)";


const date1 = DateTime.fromISO(new Date(day).toISOString());

const diff = date1.diff(DateTime.now(), ["days"]).toObject();

console.log(diff.days);

// Output

// 2.520294085648148

// Expected output

// 1. Compare day should be 2 days 
// 2. Find next day('2022-02-06') and previous day(('2022-02-04')) from `day` variable
// 3. Return date format like this:   5.2.2022 from `day` variable
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `Math.round()` or `Math.floor()` on the result as needed:

```
const { DateTime } = require("luxon");

const today = new Date();
const day =
  "Sat Feb 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)";

const date = DateTime.fromISO(new Date(day).toISOString());
const diff = date.diff(DateTime.now(), ["days"]).toObject();
const days = Math.floor(diff.days)

console.log(days); //2
```